# java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010057: multipart config was not present on Servlet

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, multipartconfig

I annotated both the resource class and the class that extends Application with @MultipartConfig, but I'm still getting the error: "org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010057: multipart config was not present on Servlet". The application server I'm using is WildFly 25.

Resource class:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@MultipartConfig
@Path("/")
public class File {
    @Path("/upload")
    @POST
    public Response upload(@Context HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getParts();
        return null;
    }
}
```

JaxRsActivator class:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
@MultipartConfig
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
}
```

Error message with stack trace:

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /test/api/upload: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010057: multipart config was not present on Servlet
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:60)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
        at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.9.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.9.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.9.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:280)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:260)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.4.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010057: multipart config was not present on Servlet
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.verifyMultipartServlet(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:543)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParts(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:532)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ContextParameterInjector$GenericDelegatingProxy.invoke(ContextParameterInjector.java:166)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final/jdk.proxy13/jdk.proxy13.$Proxy47.getParts(Unknown Source)
        at deployment.test-upload-1.0.war//test.File.upload(File.java:19)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
        ... 53 more
```

Comment: Did this work prior to WildFly 25?

Comment: I did not test with older WildFly versions.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins
Added the stack trace. Just to clarify, I know this can be done using the proprietary RESTEasy API, but I wanted to use only the Jakarta EE API so as to be independent of any particular application server (i.e. same code should work with WildFly, Payara, Open Liberty etc).

Comment: I think the issue is that `@MultipartConfig` is really a servlet annotation and REST endpoints aren't really servlets.

Comment: So there is no way to upload a file using JAX-RS and only the Jakarta EE API?

Comment: You can for sure http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/resteasy/using-rest-services-to-manage-download-and-upload-of-files/. Just not mixing Servlet and Jakarta REST API's.